# ActiveMQ redelivey with Spring Integration Aggregator not working

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-integration

i am listening a message(say original message) from an activeMq embedded broker queue. this message first moved to channel then passed to router and based on condition its passed to aggregator.Aggregator waits for one more message and then pass either partial or aggregated message to service activator class.

based on some logic activator class decide to throw exception and we expect redelivery of the message again as we have configured ActiveMQ broker side redelivery plugin.

without aggregator message is being redelivered properly and moved to DLQ if max retry reaches but if aggregator comes into picture its not being redelivered.
i am not sure but i think that aggregated message is not same as original message and thats the reason broker is not able to move that message to queue again as the message is aggregated not original.

is there any way to handle this scenario and enable redelivery or any other way to get the two original messages passed to aggregator so that move them again to queue for listening again and again untill moved to DQL by broker?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear - if the message reaches the aggregator, it is stored for aggregation purposes; it is successful from a JMS delivery perspective.

You can't retroactively "reject" a JMS message that has already been accepted from the broker's perspective.

If I understand your requirements, you would need a listener container with concurrency > 1 (so a second message can be processed) and your own code invoked by a service activator (not an aggregator) to hold up the first thread until the second one arrives; then reject both messages if your condition occurs.